# In bash script how to merge 2 Multi lines files in one file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file 1 :

```
ZRFYOK5U
 H8X7IS5G
 8TV7N4BK
```

And a file 2 :

```
1
4138
1167
```

I'd like to merge them so it looks like this :

```
ZRFYOK5U;1
 H8X7IS5G;4138
 8TV7N4BK;1167
```

Comment: Use the `paste` command.

Comment: What does this have to do with `tr`? That's for replacing characters, it has nothing to do with merging.

Comment: I removed the tr tag, paste command works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments under the question, paste is pretty straightforward to solve this problem:

```
paste -d ';' file1 file2
```

Example:

```
$  paste -d ';' <(seq 5 ) <(seq 6 10)
1;6
2;7
3;8
4;9
5;10
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can do this.

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0}NR>FNR{print a[FNR]";"$0}' file1 file2 > output.txt
```